# Ember beginner: Router and Outlets with ajax

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm just new to Ember and sure this is an easy question but cannot figure out the best way to achieve what I want.
The scenario is the following:

```
App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
root: Ember.Route.extend({
    home: Ember.Route.extend({
        route: '/',
        connectOutlets: function(router) {
            router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('home');
            router.get('homeController').connectOutlet('menu', 'menu', App.Channels.find());
            router.get('homeController').connectOutlet('video_overview', 'videoOverview', App.Featured.find());
        }
    })
})

App.Featured = Ember.Object.extend();

App.Featured.reopenClass({
find: function() {
    setRequestUrl('featured');
    establishSecureConnection();
    $.ajaxQueue({
        type: "GET",
        url: connect.url,
        data: "",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "fjsonp",
        cache: true,
        context: this,
        success: function(response){
            this.findOne(response[0].mediaId); // get the first featured object and retrieve details
            //
            console.log('Featured Video:');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
},
findOne: function(item) {
    var featuredVideo = App.Featured.create({});
    setRequestUrl('media/'+item);
    establishSecureConnection();
    $.ajaxQueue({
        type: "GET",
        url: connect.url,
        data: "",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "fjsonp",
        cache: true,
        context: featuredVideo,
        success: function(response){
            this.setProperties(response);
            //
            console.log('Featured Video details:');
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
    return featuredVideo;
}
```

So when executing the app and `Router` connects the outlet `video_overview` with content retrieved from `App.Featured.find()` I can see the response on the browser logs but values never arrives to the template.

I guess is related with the 'double' request I'm doing on `App.Featured` (first find() and then findOne()) so when I'm returning values with return `featuredVideo` is not being notified.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `App.Featured.find` does seem to return anything. I think you have to return the result of the findOne, don't you ?

Comment: Yes you're right but I've tried and seems to be the same.
I've tried to return results in findOne success function hoping to be passed to find for updating the template.
How will you return the values?

Answer (score 1):

Hy everyone again,
Finally I was messing around and take sly7_7 advices and got working!

This is the way I achieved but if anyone could explain in detail the behaviour of Ember will be appreciated.

```
App.Featured = Ember.Object.extend();
App.Featured.reopenClass({
find: function(singleItem) {
    if (singleItem){
        console.log('Returning the single item...');
        console.log(singleItem);
        //
        featuredContent.setProperties(singleItem);
    } else {
        setRequestUrl('featured');
        establishSecureConnection();
        $.ajaxQueue({
            type: "GET",
            url: connect.url,
            data: "",
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            jsonp: false,
            jsonpCallback: "fjsonp",
            cache: true,
            context: featuredContent,
            success: function(response){
                this.setProperties(App.Featured.findOne(response[0].mediaId)); // this.setProperties({'category':'hey arrives here success'});
                //
                console.log('Featured Video:');
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
    return featuredContent;
},
findOne: function(item) {
    setRequestUrl('media/'+item);
    establishSecureConnection();
    $.ajaxQueue({
        type: "GET",
        url: connect.url,
        data: "",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        jsonp: false,
        jsonpCallback: "fjsonp",
        cache: true,
        context: this,
        success: function(response){
            console.log('Featured Video content:');
            console.log(response);
            //
            this.find(response);
        }
    });
}
```

});

```
var featuredContent = App.Featured.create({});
```

Then the template recieves the changes made on featuredContent object.

Comment: The principle of defining the find method, is to return immediately something. So creating a void `App.Featured.create({})`, then setting properties as you have done it is I think a good way :). If you have to deal with more backend connection, involving relations etc... I suggest you to take a look at ember-data.

Comment: Yes sure! Few days ago I came across ember-data but unfortunatelly I've not been able to test yet.
Thanks for the advice again ;)